# Changing axis names and title of diagnostic plots

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I would like to change the axis and titles of diagnostic plot creating by basic function plot().

```
plot(mymodel, which=1)
```

For exemple I would like to achieve this.

[image]

I tried plot arguments like xlab, ylab, sub, main. But without any effect. Gives me just the following kind of error.

```
Error in plot.default(yh, r, xlab = l.fit, ylab = "Residuals", main = main,  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "axes" is not a graphical parameter
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  "axes" is not a graphical parameter
```

Then I tried function autoplot() - solution from stackoverflow discussion, that gives me other error.

```
Error in `autoplot()`:
! Objects of type lm not supported by autoplot.
```

I any way how deal with it? How rename there axis and title in diagnostic plots?

Comment: it depends on what type of object `mymodel` is and therefore the package and who wrote it. but for example if it is an `lm`, then you can try `plot(mymodel, which=1, ann = FALSE); title(xlab = 'x-axis', ylab = 'y-axis')` but yes the reason is because the authors have [set the label for you](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/plot.lm.R#L146) with no option to change it (for the case of `lm`)

Comment: Could you please share your model and data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks @rawr. I added below my own solution using among other things, the you mentioned `ann = FALSE`. But it's pretty "ugly" solution :-D

Answer (score 1):

I finally achieved it using not-so-elegant solution:

1. Invisible set labels per par() - color white (discolored inside lables and points in plot)
2. Hide athe axis
3. Recolor plot points
4. Add own axis names and title
5. Call back default par arguments.

```
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Species, data = iris)

par(mfrow=c(1,3), fg="white")

# Zero mean of residuals
plot(model, which=1, col=iris$Species, ann=FALSE, sub="", axes=FALSE)
box(col="black"); axis(1, col="black", col.ticks="black"); axis(2, col="black", col.ticks="black")
title(xlab="my x-text", ylab="my x-text", main="Zero mean of residuals")

# Normality of residuals
plot(model, which=2, col="black", ann=FALSE, sub="", axes=FALSE)
box(col="black"); axis(1, col="black", col.ticks="black"); axis(2, col="black", col.ticks="black")
title(xlab="my x-text", ylab="my x-text", main="Normality of residuals")

# Homoscedasticity (Constant residual variance)
plot(model, which=3,  ann=FALSE, sub="", axes=FALSE, col=iris$Species)
box(col="black"); axis(1, col="black", col.ticks="black"); axis(2, col="black", col.ticks="black")
title(xlab="my x-text", ylab="my x-text", main="Residual homoscedasticity")

par(mfrow=c(1,1), fg="black")
```

Final plot:
[image]

Exist any more elegant way? Too bad I lost the outliers labels inside the plots.

Comment: i don't see why you need to turn off the axes, the outlier text seems to inherit from `par(fg)` and you changed that to white. another way to suppress colors is to use "transparent" (sometimes NA works) instead of "white" as you note using white still draws the text but white on a white background. then you can use `par(mfrow = c(1, 3)); plot(model, which=1, col=iris$Species, ann=FALSE, caption = '', sub = ''); title(...); etc. etc`

Comment: You´re right. It is a combination and layering of several of my solutions. Without `fg="white"` The title (some kind of text lebel) remains above the plot.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `iris` dataset as an example. What you can do is plot your two variables and add the model with `abline`. You can now add `xlab` and `ylab` to your plot like this:

```
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, xlab = "x-axis", ylab = "y-axis")
abline(model)
```

Output:

[image]